# Percentage-width divs followed by fixed width div

Tags: css, layout, width

I am trying to achieve the following layout with CSS and HTML:

```
_____________________________________________________________________________
|  div1  33%         |  div2  33%         |  div3  33%         | div4 200px |
—————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
```

To be clear, I want div1, div2, div3 to occupy one third of the *remaining* width after the 200px div is added.

What I have tried:

1. Having div1, div2, div3, in a container div
2. Then floating div4 to the right and giving it a width of 200px.

I have tried various other things, to no avail. I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Please show what you have already done (the code) and post an example of that with [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: `calc` would work here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll have to mess with the paddings to fix the rest, but below is a working fiddle and the code. Sorry about the poor naming conventions, but you should be able to change all that to what you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/8HgHt/

```css
.third {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
}

.third:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.third_holder {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
}

.absolute_div {
  width: 200px;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: silver;
}

.whole_container {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="whole_container">

  <div class="third_holder">
    <div class="third">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="absolute_div">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `calc`

[**Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vLJAq/)

**CSS**

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* accounting for borders */
}

.wrapper {
    width:80%; /* or any width */
    margin:10px auto; /* for visualisation purposes only */
    overflow:hidden; /* float containment */
}

.wrapper div {
    float:left;
    height:100px;
}

.fixed {
    width:200px;
    background: lightblue;
}

.percent {
    width:calc((100% - 200px)/3); /* the magic bit */
    background: lightgreen;
    border:1px solid grey;
}
```

Support IE9 & up - [**http://caniuse.com/calc**](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Answer (score 0):

This can help: http://jsfiddle.net/GUcCa/1/

```js
var fxdWidth = parseInt($('#fixd').css("width").replace("px", ''));
var totalWidth = parseInt($('#fixd').parent().css("width").replace("px", ''));
$('#floating').css("width", totalWidth - fxdWidth + "px");
```

```css
.border {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.border2 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
}

#fixd {
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
}

#floating {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="border block" id="fixd">
  div4
</div>
<div class="border2 block" id="floating">
  <div class="border block">
    div1
  </div>
  <div class="border block">
    div2
  </div>
  <div class="border block">
    div3
  </div>
</div>
```